# XMLHttpRequest object not correctly returning its parameters

Tags: html, typescript, azure, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently trying to create a chat bot through Azure within an Ionic mobile application. I already have the chat bot up and running successfully within the application, but the unique identifier for the bot (secret, I believe it's called) is directly attached to the bot's site URL, meaning any user can access this bot if they access this secret.

```
<iframe id="chat" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" src='BOT_URL_AND_SECRET'></iframe>
```

I decided to try a different approach that I found online that utilizes an XMLHttpRequest object to retrieve a token and places my bot's secret in the header. This way, I can use the XMLHttpRequest object's readyState and status to access the bot without the user ever seeing the bot's secret.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  xhr: any;

  constructor() {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.open('GET', "https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens", true);
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'BotConnector ' + 'BOT SECRET VALUE');
    this.xhr.send();

    if (this.xhr.readyState == 4 && this.xhr.status == 200) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, the body of code within the if statement is never run. I did a console.log to check xhr's readyState and status values, but turns out, they are 1 and 0, respectively. Moreover, I expanded xhr's object in the console, and the readyState is 4 and the status is 200.

My question now is: how come the XMLHttpRequest object contains the parameters (i.e. readyState and status) that I need to use to provide the full URL to the HTML file, but when I try to access them, I get incorrect information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time!

You are testing them before the request has been sent (but looking at them in the console much later).

You need to wait for the ready state to change.

```
this.xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", handler);

function handler(event) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

There's no need to test that manually though. Modern browsers support a load event.

```
this.xhr.addEventListener("load", handler);

function handler(event) {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I currently have everything regarding the XMLHttpResponse object inside the constructor, so instead of creating a separate handler function, I created an anonymous function within the addEventListener method. I think this *should* work, but instead I get this error in the console: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined".

Comment: @Bosies — Different function. Different value of `this`. Use the `load` event.

Comment: I'm currently doing this: `this.xhr.addEventListener("load", function( ) { ... });`

Comment: You're right, I'm not trying to, but whenever I run the `addEventListener` function above, I'm getting the console error mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Bosies — Then you must be looking at a cached version of your code. If you don't have code which mentions `readyState`, then your code can't use an error complaining that `readyState` isn't defined.

Comment: Well, I am trying to check `xhr`'s `readyState` and `status` in order to set the bot's URL, so I have to mention `readyState`, right?

Comment: @Bosies — As I said in the answer, there is no need to test the readyState and status every time the readyState changes. Use the load event *instead*. Not as well as.

Comment: Understood; apologies for the confusion. I will update if I get things to work!